# Split an array of strings in oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split, substr

I want to use regex.substr in Oracle SQL to split a column value into multiple columns. This olumn contains strings in two formats

a)  array of strings eg: ["abc","def"]

b) single string eg "abc"

I am using

```
regexp_substr(col1, '[^",]+', 1, 1) as val1,
regexp_substr(col1, '[^",]+', 1, 2) as val2,
regexp_substr(col1, '[^",]+', 1, 3) as val3,
regexp_substr(col1, '[^",]+', 1, 4) as val4,
```

Using above, I was only able to split format "b)"
For format b) I get the below result

```
val1   val2   val3   val4
  [     abc   def     ]
```

I do not want square brackets to be included in the result. Please suggest on how to proceed with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know a priori exactly how many elements would appear in each array?

Comment: If you have to eliminate square braces use REPLACE to remove them before using regular expression. But if you don't know the size of the array your columns are going to be dynamic and that requires separate treatment. Please clarify that.

Comment: size of the array would not exceed 6 in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> regexp_substr(col1, '[^",]+', 1, 1)

It will only return the `NON-NULL` values from the array. There could be `NULL` values in the array, so the below query would return the exact position of the elements from the array considering the NULL values:

```
with data as 
(
  select '["abc","def","xyz","klm","nop","qrs"]' arr from dual union all
  select '["abc",,"xyz","klm","nop","qrs"]' arr from dual union all
  select '["abc","def",,"lkj",]' arr from dual
)
select 
    regexp_substr(arr, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) col1,
    regexp_substr(arr, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) col2,
    regexp_substr(arr, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) col3,
    regexp_substr(arr, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1) col4,
    regexp_substr(arr, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1) col5,
    regexp_substr(arr, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 6, NULL, 1) col6
from 
(
 select replace(replace(replace(arr, '['), '"'), ']') arr from data
);

COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
abc  def  xyz  klm  nop  qrs 
abc       xyz  klm  nop  qrs 
abc  def       lkj
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlekhyaB You're welcome. Please mark it as answered.